# In Python, slicing of list is not working . I want to modify a list using function by using reference, but this is not working

Tags: python, list, function, reference, slice

```
>>> num_list = list(range(5))
>>> print(num_list)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

slicing will return all elements except element of index 0.
In `delete_head()` function, `x` will be reference for a list.
`x[1:]` will return `[1,2,3,4]` and this value will be assign to `x`

```
    >>> def delete_head(x):
        x = x[1:]   

>>> delete_head(num_list)
```

But function is not working

```
>>> print(num_list)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But, even I don't use `return` statement this function is working:

```
>>> def d(u):
    del u[0]
>>> r = [1,2,3]
>>> d(r)
>>> print(r)
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Your function `delete_head` does not modify `num_list` in place and it does not return anything.

Comment: `x` is a local variable. Assigning to `x` does *not* affect the list that `x` referred to *before* the assignment.

Comment: `def delete_head(x): x.pop()`. You need to *mutate* the list referenced by `x`, not assign to `x`.

Comment: @chepner `pop()` removes the last item by default, should be `pop(0)`.

Comment: `del` is *mutating the list object*. There’s only one object visible inside and outside the function which is being *mutated*. The slicing and assigning to a local variable on the other hand does *not mutate* the object, it creates a new one.